# Use Vaadin for OfBiz website

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin, ofbiz

I am not quite an expert with all the Java EE things, so this is challenging for me:
I want to use the Vaadin Framework for the GUI of parts of an application built in OFbiz.
I have OFbiz running and a new module in the hot-deploy folder.
I also have a Vaadin application that does some stuff.
Both are separate and run in different Tomcat instances.
How would I be able to start them in the same Tomcat?

Vaadin should be integrated at a specific place in OFBiz, so I thought about using [this method](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.embedding.html) to embed it into a div.
It looks like this should work if Vaadin only gets the requests with the /VAADIN/ prefix in Tomcat, is that right? This shouldn't disturb OFBiz then?

Or should I use something else than OFBiz for the data model.
We probably want to use OFBiz for some of it's ERP/Shop functionality in the future, so I thought it would be good to start using it.
But we absolutely need to use Vaadin for the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this vaadin-test ofbiz component https://github.com/yuri0x7c1/vaadin-test

Comment: Added examples of using ofbiz delegator and dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

OFBiz has the best OOTB data model for business applications. And Vaading has the best UI for backend/business applications. In my opinion the two are natural choice. 
I have put them together in the past for a POC. Each component in OFBiz is a web app and you can add the Vaading artifacts in the component (web-inf, lib, cannot remember exact location now). The point is, when you start OFBiz your component will be deployed and Vaading started. Then you can access entity manager and service dispatcher from your Vaadin application and start creating forms, lists, tables...

Comment: Thank you! This means I add vaadin to every component I create inside the hot-deploy folder?

Comment: yes, but most likely you will not have that many componets, but few specialized compoinents with custom screens. If the you don't want to repeat the vaadin jars in every component, you can add them once (the same way it is done in framework/core component or something and reuse/include the jar in your components) but that is for later

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working with `Vaadin` in `OFBiz` but with a deeper integration:

1. create a program to convert `ofbiz` screens/forms to `vaadin` `UI` files
2. make `Vaadin` also use the `controller.xml`
3. let `vaadin` execute groovy instead of `java` files....
4. Integrate `OFBiz` groovy `dsl` in `Vaadin` screen definitions

A work in progress at our git repository at:
git clone https://gerrit.antwebsystems.com/vaadin-test

Comment: We have stopped implementation , it takes too much effort.
The work is available at the changed url: https://www.antwebsystems.com/gerrit/#/admin/projects/vaadin-test